# General method of changing the value in a vector

Tags: clojure

If I have

```
(def x [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]])
```

Is there a general method of changing any of the numbers to say 9

I know I can do

```
(assoc-in x [1 1] 9) > [[1 2 3] [4 9 6]]
```

Is there a way to do it if you don't know the index numbers. Or someway to find the index numbers first and all the information you have is you want to change the number 5 to number 9 in x

Answer (score 2):

You can use [core `replace`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/replace):

```
(mapv #(replace {5 9} %) x)
;[[1 2 3] [4 9 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers apply for your specific case but if you have arbitrary nested structure you can use `clojure.walk` namespace :

```
(defn replace-value
 [value replacement struct]
 (clojure.walk/prewalk
   (fn [x]
     (if (and (number? x) (== value x))
       replacement
       x)) struct))
```

You can of course replace `number?` by any predicate which could also be passed as arg

```
(replace-value 5 9 [[[1 5] 6 5] 1 5 [2 5]])
;; [[[1 9] 6 9] 1 9 [2 9]]
```

**EDIT : Thumbnail better version**

```
(defn replace-value [value replacement struct] 
  (clojure.walk/prewalk-replace {value replacement} struct))
```

Comment: Simpler as `(defn replace-value [value replacement struct] (clojure.walk/prewalk-replace {value replacement} struct))`. The predicate is redundant.

Comment: Your original uses [`==`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/==) - equality of *numeric* value. Is this what you want? You can't use it on strings, for example.

Comment: @Thumbnail @Joseph So if I now have `(def z (atom [["a" "b" "c"] ["d" "e" "f"]]))` and I want to use replace -value on z. As z is an atom I have to use swap!. So I tried `(swap! (replace-value "b" "g" @z))` but I am getting an error of the wrong number of args passed to swap!. Then I tried `(swap! replace-value "b" "g" @z)` but I got an error: ClassCastException user$replace_value cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IAtom  clojure.core/swap! (core.clj:2253). Is it possible to use replace value for an atom?

Comment: You will always get anomalies replacing structured elements in a structure. A common solution is to wrap the structured element in a record.

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping a structured element in a record?

Comment: My bad: carelessly, I answered a question you hadn't asked. Try `(swap! z #(replace-value "b" "g" %))`.

Comment: Ah I see how it works. I think that was me being silly/not fully understanding swap!. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes my answer was more "mathematical", I assumed he wanted to match numerical values. For this case my fn is not the best but if you want a specific predicate different from equality, it can fit it most